# What does the ?hash=item URL Param In eBay Sold URLS Mean?

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-lms, ebay-net-sdk

Example of one ebay url:
`https://www.ebay.com/itm/313606425313?hash=item4904664ae1:g:voUAAOSwP9BhH1Fj&var=612446123827`

By the time you're reading this, the link may be dead.

But that's not the point, the point is what is the meaning of the `?hash=item4904664ae1:g:voUAAOSwP9BhH1Fj` part of the url?

I understand the `313606425313` is the eBay `itemId` and if it's a `variation` *size* or *color* that is what `&var=612446123827` is for.

Does anybody know what the `?hash=item` part means?

Comment: I'm making a guess here but I think it's because eBay cycles the item number path in the URL. To avoid collisions, there is probably an additional hashing function. This reduces the odds of URL conflicts of just the item number path.